# do something only when app "starts"

Tags: android

I have an app with a single activity in it. I need to display a branding/splash screen whenever my app is started from it's icon.  My client is extremely emphatic about this, there must always be a splash screen when starting up the app.  (note that there is a legal notice on it as well, so apparently the lawyers are involved in this decision)

Of course the splash screen should *not* show up when the orientation changes, or when coming back to the app after, say, making a phone call (the app can launch the phone dialer, BTW).

I know that the app ins't always really "starting" when it comes up, as it may have been running recently and the activity kept alive.  However my client doesn't care about this technicality, to them if you start it from an icon you are "starting" the app and it must show the splash screen.

Any good strategies for this?  I don't know how to tell the difference between the various ways the activity could be initiated.

Comment: I agree with Mr. Moser's opening comment. Few, if any, mobile apps behave this way. There is a reason for that: your client's apparent objective is to piss off the users. If such a screen is not needed by Adobe, Amazon, et. al., it is dubious that your client needs it. If it is "the lawyers" who are at fault here, that begs the question of whether "the lawyers" actually have adequate experience and talent. After all, Adobe, Amazon, et. al. probably have bigger and more expensive legal teams than does your client, and if *they* don't need a splash screen...

Comment: There is no reason to use a separate activity for this. Just inflate and add the xml for the spinner if necessary. Remove or set visibility to GONE once it should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell your client that this is a REALLY bad idea. However if you really need to hack this up you none of the suggestions above will work. The only thing I can think of is to save a timestamp in a preference each time any activity pauses (onPause) and then whenever any activity resumes (onResume) check that value and if it is too long ago redirect to a splash screen activity. 
However this would be HORRIBLE.

Suggest to the client to create a standard splash screen with a dialog that say something along the lines of "yeah.. i have seen this.." and click to continue. When they press click you have confirmation that you never need to display the splash again...

Comment: The timestamp is something i've considered if necessary and might have to be the way to go.  I don't think the confirmation thing will fly, they want to make sure it is displayed each "session of use" or whatever.

Comment: Like I said .. that is a complete anti pattern and will make the app look really bad. You have to sell it to them that they are going launch an inferior product to their competitors..

Answer (score 2):

Create an activity that will show the splash screen, give it the intent filter to be started when clicking on the launcher:

```
<activity android:name="ShowMySplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

After showing the screen for how many seconds, call `finish()` on the activity and start the actual app process.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood your problem I suppose you need to work with `onStart () and onResume ()` (for displaying splash while returning to Activity after pressing `HOME`)

Regarding the splash view I would suggest use a `ImageView` (if you want to show a image as splash) and set its visibility to `GONE` & then  when your Actvity resumes or starts make the imageview display `FILL_PARENT`

& (I suppose) you are done!

Answer (score 0):

to help you with how the activity is initiated, i found following picture from the developers guide:

[image: Activity Life Cycle]

as you can see, you would want to overwrite the `onReseume()` function to display the intent/activity that is the splash screen

for example:

```
public void onResume()
{
 startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class));
}
```

where SplashScreen is a class that extends Activity

then as Zarah said:

> After showing the screen for how many seconds, call `finish()` on the
>   activity and start the actual app process.

or do something of the sort. have them press the screen too :P

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

It is created before any activities. You can set some sort of just_started flag there, check it in `onCreate()` method of you activity and act accordingly.